# How to clear memory of user control in WinForm?

Tags: .net, winforms, memory, dispose

I have a bunch of user controls, each one fills the screen on a different menu selection, I want to KILL the previous one (to clear the memory), I can't write it hard coded cause I can't know on runtime which was the previous control shown. Just removing the control from the form with         `this.Controls.Remove('uc_foo')` doesn't entirely clear memory (I checked with taskmgr)

Iterating the controls of the form with a foreach & applying `object_reference = null` causes an error "cannot assign because it is a foreach iteration variable".

Access to `this.Controls[i]` = null is denied because it's read only

so how do I get rid of it?

**UPDATE** From what I understood if I remove the control from the form and there isn't any other reference to it, eventually it'll clear from memory, it just won't be immediate like if I write `object_reference = null`, therefor I won't see the memory dropping in taskmgr right away, but the garbage collection will do it when it's in the right mood

Answer (score 3):

Correct.  Removing a control does not dispose of it.

Try

```
if (this.Controls.ContainsKey("uc_foo"))
  this.Controls["uc_foo"].Dispose();
```

Comment: In addition, ensure any event handlers which subscribed to that control are unsubscribed and collections (if applicable) are maintained when the objects are disposed.

Comment: @IAbstract - I tried to write `uc_foo.Load -= uc_foo.UC_Foo_Load;` which was the only event handler I could find, but memory didn't change. only when I write `object_reference = null` memory clears?

Comment: Unsubscribing handlers does not reduce the memory footprint. Simply good advice on cleaning up objects when they're being disposed.